# AndroidX SwipeRefreshLayout with DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, androidx, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to implement swipe to refresh functionality using AndroidX library: **androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout**

My app is using Android Databinding therefore I'd like to use observable fields to control the state of this widget.

In the past I've used [AppCompat one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout) - it has as since been deprecated.

Before, I could access the fields in the following way:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:refreshing="@{viewModel.isLoading}">
    ...
    // My RecyclerView here
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

But, this doesn't seem to work anymore - with the AndroidX equivalent. 
Am I missing something? or is there any solution/workaround to achieve this?

My project has already been fully migrated to AndroidX, there are no errors or conflicting dependencies.

Comment: What problem are you facing with android x equivalent of swiperefreshlayout?

Comment: @Kushal I don't have access to app:refreshing in the SwipeRefreshLayout.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's called [`androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout) ...

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.swiperefreshlayout/swiperefreshlayout
implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
```

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:refreshing="@{viewModel.isLoading}"
            app:onRefreshListener="@{() -> viewModel.onRefresh()}">
            ...
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</layout>
```

Then `onRefresh()`, one can get the `RecyclerView.Adapter` from the data-binding.

Comment: SwipeRefreshLayout is exposing setRefreshing() method, the Android Studio wasn't autocompleting it properly in the layout XML file and I've missed it...

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own BindingAdapter for that

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

Comment: Yes, I think custom binding adapter will solve it in this case. Actually I think I've used one with AppCompat before.